# How to get my RecyclerView frozen in .XML file?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml

To get my `RecyclerView` frozen, I do it programmatically like so:

```
myRecyclerView.setLayoutFrozen(true);
```

How to achieve the same thing in my .XML file?

Comment: [In the doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setLayoutFrozen(boolean)) you can see that when you set an adapter, the recycler view will exit frozen mode so it makes sense that you don't have an xml attribute to do that. You have to froze it after you set the adapter

Comment: @Kilarn123 Oh yes, you're right, make sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Kilarn123 I came back to same problem and found your useful comment. Please add the your comment as an answer so the question cannot be deleted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Added after the comments*

[In the doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setLayoutFrozen(boolean)), you can see that when you set an adapter, the recycler view will exit frozen mode so it makes sense that you don't have an xml attribute to do that. You have to froze it after you set the adapter.